# How do I use a sprite background image to display once on an element (no-repeat)?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-sprites

I wish to add a jQuery icon to another class which is added by another plugin ([jquery.tablesorter.js](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)), specifically I wish to add the icon `ui-icon-triangle-1-n` to the `.headerSortUp` class from `tablesorter`.

I am trying to add the following class but can't for the life of me how to work out a sprite for it.

```
table.sortable thead tr .headerSortUp {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  background: url(jquery-ui/css/smoothness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png) 0 -16px;
}
```

I've not worked with CSS sprites before so am not entirely sure how to do this.

The situation I see is I only want a portion of the background image to appear, but I want that positioned to the right center of the text and no-repeat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an excellent tutorial on background image crop for sprites here:
[css-background-image-hacks](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/)

The trick is to use the pseudo selectors `:after` or `:before` to place the icon into the header without having to add an additional element into the html structure.

And here I add a working demo using the tablesorter plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/FXq8b/

```
.tablesorter thead tr {
  line-height:16px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.headerSortUp:after, .headerSortDown:after {
   content:"";
   float:right;
   width:16px;
   height:16px;
   margin:0 5px 0 0;
   background:url('http://www.wooldalejunior.org.uk/ui/vendor/jquery.ui/css/smoothness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png');
   background-position:0 -16px;
}
.headerSortDown:after {
   background-position:-64px -16px;
}
```

now you just need to move as many times x 16px to the left and up to reach the desired icons (for another example ... up -> `background-position: 0 -48px;` down -> `background-position: -64px -48px` ... or up -> `background-position: -96px -192px;` down -> `background-position: -64px -192px`, you just need to count how many icons from top and from the left edge your desired icon lies on the image: http://jsfiddle.net/FXq8b/1/).

Comment: Now that is very neat and precisely the sort of thing I was looking for. Very interesting to know you can style pseudo elements like that!

Answer (score 0):

You just create box and put image into this box:

```
table.sortable thead tr .headerSortUp,
table.sortable thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background: url("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png") no-repeat;   
    display: inline-block; /* or block */
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}
table.sortable thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-position: 0 -46px;
}
table.sortable thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-position: -65px -46px;
}
```

With `background-position` you navigate inside your sprite by X and Y coordinate.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/865VD/

Comment: as mentioned in my original post, I can not add a new presentational element as I do not control the plugin. Of course I could modify the source to the `tablesorter` plugin, though this is undesirable.